# pam_cracklib on Linux: how to disable credits

Tags: linux, pam, cracklib

The pam_cracklib 'minlen' does not work as I want it to.
PAM allows passwords even with lesser length than it is set to with the 'minlen' option.
It gives credits (by default 1) to the 'upper-case', 'lower-case', 'digit' and 'other-character'.

Therefore if minlen is set to 8, the following passwords are allowed as valid:

- 'abcdefg' (length = 7+1 credit for use of lower-case characters)
- 'abcde1'(length = 6 + 1 credit for use of lower-case characters + 1 credit for using a digit)
- 'Abcd1' (length = 5 + 1 credit for use of lower-case characters + 1 credit for using a digit + 1 for using an upper case character)
- 'Ab1$' (length = 4 + 1 credit for use of lower-case characters + 1 credit for using a digit + 1 for using an upper case character + 1 for using an other character)

I do not want PAM give credits to these class of characters and want to strictly enforce minlen as specified irrespective of what type of characters are used in the password.
I also tried with the following setting, but that didn't help:

```
password required pam_cracklib.so lcredit=0 dcredit=0 ucredit= ocredit=0 minlen=8
```

Comment: did you also try it with the missing `ucredit=0`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `pam_cracklib` to enforce a minimum password length; `pam_unix` will happily do this. Just use `min=8` or `minlen=8` (it's `min` in older versions of PAM; check your `pam_unix` man page).

Comment: I checked out that, but my pam_unix (RHEL 6.3) does not have the 'min' or 'minlen' option.
The man page I see on my system is similar to the one found at: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix

Answer (score 0):

That configuration ought to work. If you are doing this as `root` or with superuser privileges, you will need to add the `enforce_for_root` argument to the `pam_cracklib.so` line. Otherwise, it will complain about the `BAD PASSWORD`, but will still allow it.